# Kohana - one function on every controller

Tags: web, kohana

I have a project in Kohana 3.3.
I have a lot of controllers, models etc.

Now, I want add one functionality - close the whole site for all users.

Where I can add function, which for example, will redirect users to http://mypage.com/website_is_close ?

Example:

```
function check(){
    $isClose = DB::query(.....)
    if($isClose) header("Location: http://mypage.com/website_is_close");
    return false;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In `Controller_Base` all other controllers extend from. E.g.

File application/classes/Controller/Base.php

```
class Controller_Base extends Controller_Template {

    public function before()
    {
        $isClose = DB::query(.....)
        if($isClose)
        {
            HTTP::redirect("http://mypage.com/website_is_close");
            exit ;
        }

        parent::before();
    }
}
```

All other classes should extend from that class e.g

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Base {}
```

I personally use this also for every subdirectory e.g.

```
// As all controllers in the user folder probably need to be supplied with a user anyway
class Controller_User_Base extends Controller_Base {} 

class Controller_User_Profile extends Controller_User_Base {}
```

Comment: Hmm.. i add my function in /system/classes/Kohana/Controller.php in before() function.
It's work :) But this is correct?

Comment: No. You should not have to change system code. Do not take the easy way out here! Refactor!

Comment: I use `Controller_Template` class for such purposes. All other Controllers extend it and have all the non-private methods. To correctly add new parent method refer to Kohana Cascading Filesystem docs(http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files).

Comment: @s.webbandit as long as that Controller is in `application/classes/Controller/Template.php` it is valid :) and probably the easiest solution for OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to **add a "catch all" route** to the *beginning* of your routes list.

It would catch all URLs and would point to a controller that you would create. This is far cleaner than hacking away at a base controller.

How does this look?

```
Route::set('closed', '(<url>)', array('url' => '.*'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'Closed',
    'action' => 'index',
));
```